# mounted hfs+ drive with hfsprog, now disk corrupt

Tags: hard-drive, filesystems, mount, hfs

Following several other threads, I mounted an HFS+ external hard drive using

```
sudo mount -t hfsplus -o force,rw /dev/sdXY /media/mntpoint
```

then unmounted.

Now the harddrive is unreadable: `Input/Output error...`

How can I repair this? What went wrong?

dmesg shows:

> File system was not cleanly unmounted, running fsck.hfsplus is recommended.  mounting read-only.

Was there a special way to unmount? Can it be reversed?

Comment: If you have a backup image, the safest would be to restore from that.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the dmesg log, unmounting and running fsck.hfsplus on the device seemed to solve the issue. Although fsck finished with a "not succesful in repairing disk" message, the original files have been restored and are accessible.